# Using ansible to modify a JBoss proprty with out changing all property tags

Tags: xml, jboss, ansible, appdynamics

The AppDynamics java agent requires the JBoss Domain.xml and Host.xml files to be modified in order to run.

To make AppDynamics work, I must add a "property" element with two attributes.

`<property name="jboss.modules.system.pkgs" value="com.singularity"/>`

I have also tried to add the element and attributes int he same code block, but received a ansible error stating the element and attributes are exclusive:

```
      xml: 
        path:/opt/jboss/domain/configuration/domain.xml
        xpath: /ns:fomain/ns:systemproperties
        namespaces: {'ns': 'urn:jboss:domain:5.0'}
        prettyprint: yes
        add_children:
        - property
        attribute: 'name'
        value: 'test'
```

The issue I am running into is this: At the same path there is a duplicate property with different attributes that must remain unchanged

`<property name="java.net.preferIPv4Stack" value="true"/>`

When using Ansible, I always seem to overwrite ALL the "property" elements.

I have tried adding the property element with the attributes on the same like  (as if it were the property name) but receive a python error:

```
        add_children:
        - "property name='test' value='test'"
```

The latest version of the Ansible code I am using is as follows:

```
      xml: 
        path:/opt/jboss/domain/configuration/domain.xml
        xpath: /ns:fomain/ns:systemproperties
        namespaces: {'ns': 'urn:jboss:domain:5.0'}
        prettyprint: yes
        add_children:
        - property
    - name: update attributes
      xml:
        path:/opt/jboss/domain/configuration/domain.xml
        xpath: /ns:fomain/ns:systemproperties
        namespaces: {'ns': 'urn:jboss:domain:5.0'}
        content: attribute
        attribute: 'name'
        value: 'test'
      when: not 'name'
```

I am at a loss on how to deal with duplicated element names with different attributes via ansible.

In the end I would need to end up with  this:

```
<system-properties>
        <!-- IPv4 is not required, but setting this helps avoid unintended use of IPv6 -->
        <property name="java.net.preferIPv4Stack" value="true"/>
        <property name="jboss.modules.system.pkgs" value="com.singularity"/>
</system-properties>
```

Any help would be great appreciated. I know the answer is staring m in the face, but I just don't see it

And added point would also to ensure I don't have identical elements with identical attributes as well.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're using a modern version of JBoss EAP, in that case you should use jboss cli commands rather than manually modify the XML configuration files. The CLI command for your modification would be `/system-property=jboss.modules.system.pkgs:add(value=com.singularity)`

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. I wish I was more familiar with JBoss CLI. I will try what you advised.